# Need to connect to virtual box guest from host

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, ping, nat

The guest is a NAT device. From Ipconfig I can have an ip adress but I can't ping it from the host. do you have some ideas on how to connect to  virtual box guest from host ?

Host OS: 2008 windows server
Guest Os: Windows XP

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to a Bridged network device, or switch it to a Host-only network device. NAT will only allow other guests who are NAT'ed to connect to it due to how NAT networking works.